# Express javascript unit test 'TypeError: app.address is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unit-testing, supertest

I have checked other answers like this one [Mocha API Testing: getting 'TypeError: app.address is not a function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986863/mocha-api-testing-getting-typeerror-app-address-is-not-a-function) and it seems the main issue for the error is not exporting the server but I think I am doing that.

Here is my test file spec.js

```
var request = require('supertest');
describe('loading express', function () {
  var server;
  beforeEach(function () {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve('./index')];
  server = require('./index');
});
  afterEach(function (done) {
    server.close(done);
  });
  it('responds to /', function testSlash(done) {
  request(server)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200, done);
  });
```

Here is my index.js file

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import _ from "lodash";
import serveStatic from "serve-static";

const port = 8000;

export default (app) => {
  app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
  app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    })
  );
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(serveStatic("dist/", { index: ["index.html"] }));
  app.use(cookieParser());

  if (_.isNil(process.env.APP_ENV)) {
    process.env.APP_ENV = "LOCAL";
  } 
  // ... A load of variables and functions in here

  // simple function to test
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.status(200).send('ok');
   });

   var server = app.listen(port, function () {
   var port = server.address().port;
   console.log('Example app listening at port %s', port);
 });
  module.exports = server;
};
```

Comment: I would try and remove the export default (app) altogether and code like the thread you mention, ie var app = express();  ... ; var server = app.listen(3000, function () {..., then module.exports server comes as last line, not inside the export default (app).
I think the issue is this. give it a shot and good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index.js` is exporting a function which takes `app` as an argument. So the import of `index.js` is a function which must be called with `app`.

spec.js

```js
  server = require('./index');
  // replace with
  server = require('./index')(app);
```

Assuming this remains as a function, and you call it with `app` in `spec.js`, as above, then you can get `server` by replacing `module.exports = server;` with `return server;`.

test.js

```js
  module.exports = server;
  // replace with
  return server;
```

Separately, there is also a mixture of ES Modules (`import/export`) and CommonJS Modules (`module.exports/require`) here which can result in a variety of weird behavior. If you can standardize on just one of these, it'll go a long way.

But if you continue to use `require('./index')` to import `index.js` which is an ES Module, you may need to try `require('./index').default` instead, to grab that `default` export.