# TypeError: app.address is not a function - Shopify App Node.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, mocha.js, shopify

The issue is already describe here

[Mocha API Testing: getting 'TypeError: app.address is not a function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986863/mocha-api-testing-getting-typeerror-app-address-is-not-a-function)

Tried to test my Shopify app using Mocha, Chai created with Nextjs. Tried several workarounds mentioned on the above link. But it still produces the following error

```
GET requests
    GET /customers
      1) Success should return true


  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) GET requests
       GET /customers
         Success should return true:
     TypeError: app.address is not a function
      at serverAddress (node_modules\chai-http\lib\request.js:282:18)
      at new Test (node_modules\chai-http\lib\request.js:271:53)
      at Object.obj.<computed> [as get] (node_modules\chai-http\lib\request.js:239:14)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\appTest.js:44:10)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

**apptest.js**

```
let chai = require("chai");
let chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const server = require("../server/index");

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe("GET requests", () => {
  describe("GET /customers", () => {
    it("Success should return true", (done) => {
      chai.request(server)
        .get("/customers")
        .end((err, res) => {
          console.log('Error => ', err);
          console.log('Response => ', res);
          res.body.success.should.equal(true)
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

**server.js**

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import createShopifyAuth, { verifyRequest } from "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth";
import Shopify, { ApiVersion } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import Koa from "koa";
import Router from "koa-router";
import next from "next";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

dotenv.config();
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({
  dev,
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const AccessToken = {};

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https:\/\/|\/$/g, ""),
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.January22,
  //API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October20,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.MemorySessionStorage(),
});


const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS = {};


app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  server.keys = [Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY];

  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      async afterAuth(ctx) {
        // Access token and shop available in ctx.state.shopify
        const { shop, accessToken, scope } = ctx.state.shopify;

        AccessToken["access_token"] = accessToken;

        ctx.cookies.set("accessToken", accessToken, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "none",
        });

        ctx.cookies.set("shop_name", shop, {
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "none",
          httpOnly: false,
        });

        const host = ctx.query.host;
        ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = scope;

        ctx.cookies.set("HOST", host, {
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "none",
          httpOnly: false,
        });

        //Database Connection
        const shopName = shop.replace("myshopify.com", "");
        const formattedShopName = shopName
          .replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "")
          .replace(/\s+/g, "")
          .toLowerCase();
        const connectionStr = `${process.env.CONNECTION_STRING}${formattedShopName}`;
        await mongoose
          .connect(connectionStr, {
           // creds
          })
          .then(async () => {
            console.log("database connected");
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));

        // Redirect to app with shop parameter upon auth
        ctx.redirect(`/?shop=${shop}&host=${host}`);
      },
    })
  );

  router.get("/customers", async (ctx, next) => {
    // Logics to fetch customers
  });

  const handleRequest = async (ctx) => {
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
  };


  router.get("(/_next/static/.*)", handleRequest); // Static content is clear
  router.get("/_next/webpack-hmr", handleRequest); // Webpack content is clear
  router.get("(.*)", verifyRequest(), handleRequest);

  server.use(router.allowedMethods());
  server.use(router.routes());
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });


});
```

**index.js**

```
require("@babel/register")({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
  ignore: ["node_modules"],
  compact: false,
});

// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require("./server.js");
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shopify-app-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopify's node app for CLI tool",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
    "build": "NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1 next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node.git"
  },
  "author": "Shopify Inc.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shopify/shopify-app-node/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^2.0.6",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-utils": "^2.0.6",
    "@shopify/dates": "^1.1.5",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^5.0.3",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^6.2.0",
    "@szhsin/react-menu": "^3.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.1.0",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.9",
    "next": "^12.0.8",
    "next-env": "^1.1.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.4.7",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-router": "^6.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "read-json-lines-sync": "^2.2.0",
    "recharts": "^2.1.9",
    "rsuite": "^5.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.6",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.10",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.14.0",
    "supertest": "^6.2.4"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,css,json,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Found a solution to this yet? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @EthanNeedsHelpCoding Not found any solutions, please let me know if you have one